# How to get multiple queryset from textarea in django

Tags: python, django

I have a text area in which user inputs multiple values in different line and i want to get object for every single line in text area and send it to template. How i should do it.?

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    search = request.GET.get('search')
    slist = []
    for i in range(4):
        slist.append(search.splitlines()[i])
    sdata = Stock.objects.all().filter(slug=slist)
    return render(request, 'stocks/searchbar.html', {'sdata':sdata})
```

I'm trying to do it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
sdata = Stock.objects.filter(slug__in=search.splitlines())
```

Since `search.splitlines()` returns a list and `slug` is, I assume, a CharField, you need the `in` clause in your query.